# 80s or 90s film featuring kids performing some sort of ritual or seance in a church

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this movie w/my mom when I was little.  I remember no actor/actress names, only pieces of the movie itself.  English language, color, released somewhere between 1980-1995.

Here are plot pieces that I remember:  Group of kids (girls and boys) standing in a circle holding hands.  They're in a building, likely a church or cathedral. One boy is speaking; they're performing some kind of ritual or seance.  A girl stands in the middle of the circle, blindfolded.  Loud noise/earth shaking occurs and a giant bell, like from a cathedral, drops on top of the girl standing in the middle.  She disappears.

Years later another group of kids track down the same -now grown up- people from the first ritual and convince them to perform it again, with one of their own girls standing in place of the one who was lost or disappeared.

Please, please, PLEASE help me remember the name of this movie.  I remember really liking it and would love to find/add it to my collection.

Comment: In future, please do us a favor and use descriptive titles that explain what you're asking. "Help me find this film" and the like are useless to us.

Comment: Thank you so much Catija!  You have answered a long-held question for me.  For both your help and grammar critique, I am very thank full :)

Comment: ... I didn't answer your question... Walt did... but I'm glad that you've found the film you're looking for. Please thank him by clicking on the check mark on the answer to show that it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

[The Watcher in the Woods](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081738/combined) from 1980 with Bette Davis.

> When a normal American family moves into a beautiful old English house in a wooded area, strange, paranormal appearances befall them in this interesting twist to the well-known haunted-house tale. Their daughter Jan sees, and daughter Ellie hears, the voice of a young teenage girl who mysteriously disappeared during a total solar eclipse decades before...

You can see the ritual scene with the bell falling on the girl in the trailer: