Does anyone know what movie this is? Help plz
This is a very old movie, probably came out in the 80s or 90s. Group of kids (girls and boys) standing in a circle holding hands. They're in a church or cathedral. One boy is speaking; they're performing some kind of ritual or seance. A girl stands in the middle of the circle, blindfolded. There's a loud noise/earth shaking occurs and a giant bell, like from a cathedral, drops on top of the girl standing in the middle. She disappears. Years later another group of kids track down the same, now grown up, people from the first ritual and convince them to perform it again, with one of their own girls standing in place of the one who was lost. I really would like to know the name of this film. Please help! :)

http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44692/80s-or-90s-film-featuring-kids-performing-some-sort-of-ritual-or-seance-in-a-chu

The movie is The Watcher in the Woods (1980)

Helen and Paul Curtis (Carroll Baker and David McCallum) and their daughters Jan (Lynn-Holly Johnson) and Ellie (Kyle Richards), move into a manor. Mrs. Aylwood (Bette Davis), the owner of the residence, notices that Jan bears a striking resemblance to her daughter, Karen, who disappeared inside a chapel near the village 30 years previously.
Jan begins to see strange blue lights in the woods, triangles and glowing objects. Eventually, Ellie goes to buy a puppy she names "Nerak" (an anagram for Karen). After seeing the reflection of the name "Nerak" (Karen spelled backwards), Jan finds out about the mystery of Mrs. Aylwood's missing daughter.
Several strange occurrences appear, beginning with Mrs. Aylwood saving Jan from drowning after she falls into a pond looking at a blue circle, and ending with Jan finding a man named John, who explains that Karen did disappear but has not died. He tells her that in a seance-like ceremony, Karen disappeared after lightning struck the tower and a bell fell on top of her. They find out that the disappearance of Karen is linked to a solar eclipse. Jan figures out she needs to repeat the sequence through the strange possession of Ellie.
In the chapel, something possesses Ellie and explains the accidental switch that took place 30 years ago. Ellie explains that Karen was taken to another dimension, while an alien-like being, the Watcher, came to earth. The Watcher then appears independently as a pillar of light, fueled by the "circle of friendship". It engulfs Jan and lifts her into the air, but Jan's friend Mike Fleming (Benedict Taylor) intercedes and pulls her away before the Watcher disappears. At the same time, the eclipse ends and Karen, still the same age as when she disappeared, reappears – still blindfolded. She removes the blindfold as her mother enters the chapel.

The seance scene can be seen at about 30 seconds into the trailer.



